# different tree for the same data set

Tags: classification, data-mining, weka

I am working on Pima Indians Diabetes Database in Weka. I noticed that for decision tree J48 the tree is smaller as compared to the Random Tree.
I am unable to understand why it is like this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though they both are decision trees, they employ different algorithms for constructing the tree, which will (most likely) give you a different outcome:

- [J48](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/trees/J48.html) prunes the tree by default after it built its tree ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm)).
- [RandomTree](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/trees/RandomTree.html) (when using default parameters) inspects a maximum of `log2(num_attributes)` attributes for generating splits.